# Angular populate select with object of objects

Tags: json, angularjs, object

Give this object of objects: (filled with way more)

```
$scope.object = {
"activities":
{
    "1": {
        "name": "Watch a movie",
    }
    "2": {
        "name": "Chill at home",
    }
},

"people":
{
    "1": {
        "name": "with your best friend",
         }
}
```

How can I fill my select with all names of activities?

Right now I have

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `ng-options="activity.name for (key , activity) in object.activities"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select ng-model="currentID" 
ng-options="id as activity.name for (id, activity) in object.activities">
</select>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/p3cQQ0YnI0Fok2BoXQrX?p=preview)**